# Equal Temperament as a Stack of Just Intervals

Tags: piano, tuning, acoustics, temperament, just-intonation

Recently I came up with interesting discovery how to get equally tempered tones by using a stack of just intervals 3/2 and 5/4. Since they are a part of most harmonic cord, major triad, should be caught very accurate.

The kernel of my theory is using the stack of 7 perfect fifths (3/2) and 1 major third (5/4) to get a single equally tempered tone.

(3/2)^7 * 5/4 * 1/16 = 1.3348388671875

The ratio must be divided by 16 (or 2^4) because the tone I'm looking for went 4 octaves up.

In this example the result is perfect fourth. Mathematical precision is till 5th digit after the decimal point. The error is 0.00128 cents. Repeating same stack 11 times gives a final error of 11 * 0.00128 = 0.01408 cents.

I wrote an article about this discovery but many musicians claim this is not possible in terms of acoustics because lot more events occur, for example inharmonicity and octave stretching. Due to imperfection of the instruments this remains just theoretical.

https://nearequaltemperament.com/

Although this may never be achieved in practice, I believe the math behind this theory is exceptional. Many roots of 2 could be expressed by small fractions of the first 3 prime numbers (2, 3 and 5). Everything from 2^(1/12) to 2^(11/12) could be calculate very accurate by stacking above expression 11 times. Reversing the ratios is legit too.

Is it possible to tune a piano using this method of stacking 7 P5s and 1 M3? I'm expecting better accuracy up to 246 times but what would be the actual results?

So far the best procedure I can offer for tuning is this one:

https://nearequaltemperament.com/inverse-stack/

Is it efficient enough? Is it going to accumulate errors or it's error free?

Another rough procedure that pushes the tuning process to its maximum is:

https://nearequaltemperament.com/small-scale/

Since the stack contains twice less steps but larger ratios, is there any possibility to get it done without accumulating errors?

Comment: Is there a question here? In any event, even though it's to within the fifth decimal of a true equal-tempered fourth, it's a little bit different.  If you use this interval in a 12-tone chromatic scale, the resulting intervals won't be equal. And the fact that you got to this interval by stacking just intervals doesn't change the fact that it's somewhat different from a just fourth of 4/3. And suppose you start on F and end up on B-flat (well, A sharp). If you use those seven stacked white notes for your scale, you'll still have Pythagorean tuning there with its 81:64 thirds, not 5:4.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because it now contains a question.

Comment: I think the question makes for a good discussion; however, the allocations of the system are not clear (to me). I did read the linked page. I don't see a procedure for using such an approximation. The procedure for equal temperament (as given to me by a piano tuner) is tune octaves (from some start) exactly; then tune fourths 2 beats sharp and fifths one beat flat; the other notes are made from these. You could use 89/84 as the ratio (ttw) rather than 18/17 (Vincenzio Galilei) to approximate equal temperament.

Comment: Please clarify: your procedure is to start with C, tune 7 fifths up and a major third up, and somewhere in the process go down by 4 octaves in order to tune the note F. Then by repeating the procedure from F tune Bb, and so on until all 12 notes are tuned?

Comment: The main webpage explains only the conception and math. The procedures, 3 of them, are in supplementary articles. So far the best process I can offer is called Fast Inverse Stack https://nearequaltemperament.com/inverse-stack/ . Forward Stack is for education/testing purpose. Small Scale Stack is a rough idea to reduce the steps even further, the absolute limit.

Comment: Note that, mathematically speaking, this *cannot* be error free as 2^(1/12) is an irrational: it can be *estimated* but not calculated with infinite precision using fractions (hence the name irrational).

Comment: @Tom "irrational" doesn't mean "impossible"; for example, you can create a line segment with a length of exactly √2 by creating a unit square and using its diagonal to define your line segment.  The fact that you can't represent it as the sum of a finite series of rationals doesn't mean that it can't exist.

Comment: Vinkelman: to tune from C to F, you use the intervening G, D, A, E, B, F♯, and C♯.  Then to get from F to B♭, you have to retune C.  Doesn't that throw your temperament off?  Ok, you can use the upper C and retune it later, but eventually you're going to start having to reuse notes that you've already set, aren't you?

Comment: @phoog I never said it was impossible or that it does not exit, I said that "it cannot be calculated with infinite precision *using fractions*". Hence, using fraction, the calculation of this irrationnal number *cannot* be error free.

Comment: @Tom I think you mean to say a finite number of fractions. A countably infinite number of fractions summed can exactly equal an irrational number. That’s basically what an infinite decimal expansion is. In any case, for real world scenarios, the precision that anything can be done in the real world is limited by physics well before the mathematical limits. In other words, we can’t precisely tune exactly to a rational number any better than we can to an irrational one.

Comment: @Tom Oh yes.  That's true.  But the error inherent in the contemplated system does seem to be so small that it's probably negligible compared to the relatively low precision of human piano tuners.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, I should have put finite!

Comment: @phoog I was just being nitpicky ;)

Comment: Note that in 12-EDO, P5 = 7 semitones and M3 = 4 semitones, so 7*P5 + M3 = 53 semitones.  So it seems that OP has rediscovered the approximation [P5 = 31/53 octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/53_equal_temperament) from another perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the math. **The problem is the efficiency of the tuning algorithm** (or, lack of efficiency, as the case may be).

Since the algorithm is monotonically increasing (up to the point of octave correction), let's begin by tuning the lowest pitch, A0, which we'll accept as given.

Since our goal initially is to tune all 12 chromatic pitches as accurately as possible, we can forego the octave corrections for now. This won't affect the math, since multiplication is commutative. We can do all the fifths and thirds first, and deal with the octaves later.

Thus, to tune the each of the fourths most accurately (without regard to octave) requires 8 operations: 7 fifths and 1 third.

Thus, tuning each of the 12 chromatic pitches to the greatest accuracy requires a minimum of 8 * 12 = 96 operations. (And, since tuning each fourth ascends four octaves, we would need a piano with 12 * 4 = 36 octaves.) Limiting our piano to 7 total octaves, and having tuned the equivalent of one of them, we now need an additional 12 * 6 = 72 octave tunings.

Hence, **a total of 168 operations** involving 32 working octaves is required.

Further, since shortening our keyboard to an actual 7 working octaves only requires changing the order of operations (doing the octave corrections as needed), we still need a minimum of 168 total operations.

**In other words, on a seven octave keyboard (7 * 12 = 84 keys), every key must be tuned twice, on average, to achieve the ideal result.**

Comment: In my best case scenario you need only 2 octaves to work on. Take a look supplementary articles, i.e. Fast Inverse Stack https://nearequaltemperament.com/inverse-stack/ . Explains the whole process efficiently by working on 2 octaves only, C3-C4, the ones we can hear very accurate.

Comment: @Vinkelman If that's the question you want answered, please put it in your post.

Comment: @Vinkelman Looking at the "fast inverse stack", I see it takes 99 steps to tune a single octave. That leaves 6 octaves left to be tuned, which requires another 6*12 = 72 steps, for a grand total of 171 steps. Less efficient than the procedure outlined above.

Comment: @Vinkelman I should reiterate that I see no problem with the math (i.e., the accuracy of the tuning), only the efficiency compared to standard practice.